# Application crash while using spinner

Tags: crash, spinner

This method is to get the inputs that includes three `EditText` boxes and one spinner which is populated from `string-array`.The click of the button is the trigger for undertaking the calculations. While the `OnClick` method is pressed the application crashes. The code is as follows

```
package biz.avksons.siddharth.hydro_basic_calc;

import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UoE extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Define variables for Spinner here
    Spinner spinner_1;
    String spin_select;
    boolean dbug=true;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uoe);


    }


    // ************************************************************************************
    // Start the method to calculate the units of electricity here

    public void onUoECalc_ButtonClick(View v) {
         /* Define Custom method for calculating the Units of electricity on clicking the Calculate button*/
        //Processing variable for count
        boolean flag = false; // Used to check if the inputs done in the EditText are valid or not, else there will an exception which would lead to application crash

        /* Initiate the Variables here*/
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        //Allocate the ids of EditText to the variables for further use
        EditText et_capacity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_uoe_capacity);
        EditText et_plf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_uoe_plf);
        EditText et_availability = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_uoe_availability);
        EditText et_energy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_uoe_mus);


        //Variable for deciding Timeperiod
        Double time_period = 365.00;



        //---DEBUG <code></code>
        if (dbug)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Spiner selection : " + spin_select, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        //Set flag to true only if the inputs in the two edittext, discharge and head are sensible inputs
        if (checkedittext(et_capacity) && checkedittext(et_plf) && checkedittext(et_availability)) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            //If the inputs in discharge are not sensible then display the message to input a sensible input before moving further
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter valid inputs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Set the EditText box of the output to blank if the inputs are not valid as tested in the above statements
            et_capacity.setText("");
        }


        // do this operation only if the flag is set to true which are tested above
        if (flag == true) {

            //-------Initiating Spinner here
            addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
            // Set selection default for Spinner here
          //  spinner_1.setSelection(1);

            //--------Allocation of Spin Button Here-------------
            if (dbug)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Spin_select"+ spin_select, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            switch (spin_select) {
                case "1 yr":
                    time_period = 365.00;
                case "6 mon":
                    time_period = 180.00;
                case "3 mon":
                    time_period = 90.00;
            }
            //-------End of Spin Button--------------


            //Assign the values here
            Double d_capacity = Double.parseDouble(et_capacity.getText().toString());
            Double d_plf = Double.parseDouble(et_plf.getText().toString());
            Double d_availability = Double.parseDouble(et_availability.getText().toString());

            //-DEBUG Code----
            if(dbug)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Time Period selected" + time_period.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Double d_energy = Double.valueOf((d_capacity * 1000 * 24 * time_period * d_plf * d_availability) / 1000000);


            et_energy.setText(Double.toString(Math.round(d_energy))); // In MW
            // capacity.setText(String.format(".2%f",Double.toString(C)));
        }

    }

    //Method to check for validity of contents in edittext
    public boolean checkedittext(EditText edtxt) {
        if (edtxt.getText().toString().matches("")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //--------Method to get the selected option from Spinner

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        //------Declare a variable on Spinner and allocate the id here
        spinner_1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin_uoe_period);
        spinner_1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                spin_select = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void onHelp_UoE(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter valid figures in the boxes mentioned and select the period you are interested in; from the dropdown menu before pressing calculate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

The error in Logcat is as follows

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at biz.avksons.siddharth.hydro_basic_calc.UoE.onUoECalc_ButtonClick(UoE.java:84)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to find the `NullPointerException` error which as per the code suggests that the `spinner_select` variable is not initialized. My understanding tells me that the `spinner_select` variable should be initialized every time the method is called.

Request for assistance..Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have missed

```
break;
```

in switch case statement